# Cross-over distortion thanks to short circuit protection

Tags: amplifier, distortion

I am trying to build a AB Amplifier for school with some darlington transistors. Everything seemed to go fine until I added the short circuit protection. From that moment a cross-over distortion occured as per below:

[image: AB Amplifier + Shortcut protection with cross-over]

Does anyone know how to solve this distortion?

Comment: Where does the short circuit protection circuit idea come from? It just looks like a voltage clamp to me.

Comment: Try removing the 1000uF output coupling capacitor.

Comment: It is always beneficial for everyone to be able to see what you see by providing the .asc file in a pastebin. E.g. I have no idea (well, actually I have, but I am not sure) what node n013 is

Comment: I am going to lunch now, but  hint: replace Q2 and Q3 by ideal transistors and look at it again

Comment: @MichaelKaras was right about removing the 1000uF capacitor, but we found out that the short circuit protection was on the same spot after all.

Answer (score 2):

The crossover distortion is caused by the fact that you've basically put two back-to-back diodes — the B-E junction of Q2 and the B-C junction of Q3 — in series with your load, and the forward voltage drop of these junctions prevents current from flowing through the load near the zero crossings.

Also, note that your current limiter will only work with positive output voltages; a proper design would work on both positive and negative output peaks. This is normally done by sensing the current directly in the output stage and reducing the drive to the output transistors if necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't the input to the push-pull stage be inserted between D2 and D3 to make it nice and symmetrical? (+ resistor between D1 and negative of course)

Comment: @OskarSkog: It really doesn't matter. The bias current flowing through the diodes is always greater than the peak signal current.